# nth-child affecting groups of 3 inputs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an input form handling course applications that dynamically adds extra inputs depending on the number of applicants - each applicant fills in their name, e-mail and telephone number. So if the user selects 2 applicants, the form adds 3 new inputs after the default 3, and so on.

I'd like to improve the usability of the form by alternating the background colour of each group of three inputs, e.g. the first three are grey, the next three are white, the next three are grey etc.

I *think* I can do this with nth-child, but I don't know how. The inputs are in their own div so it's easy to affect them, I just don't know what to put in the nth-child brackets to make it happen.

Comment: Some basic HTML would be useful. A JSFiddel perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div:nth-child(6n),
div:nth-child(6n-1),
div:nth-child(6n-2){
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bmMjm/

Comment: This worked great once I got the selector right, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a pattern that repeats every 6 items. You therefore need to base it on `:nth-child(6n)`. Unfortunately, this gets a bit verbose...

```
input:nth-child(6n+1), input:nth-child(6n+2), input:nth-child(6n+3) {
    background: white;
}
input:nth-child(6n+4), input:nth-child(6n+5), input:nth-child(6n) {
    background: lightgrey;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yaL4/)

Obviously the default is `white`, so the first block isn't strictly speaking necessary.